# Is the function $n \mapsto n - \phi(n)$ surjective on odd natural numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I was tinkering with elementary number theory and encountered the following problem.

Is the function
\begin{align}
f:2\mathbb{N} + 1 &\to 2\mathbb{N} + 1 \\ 
n &\mapsto n -\phi(n)
\end{align}
surjective?

Comment: Read the Wikipedia article about [noncototients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncototient).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the stronger form of Goldbach's conjecture (every even number greater than $6$ is the sum of two distinct primes) holds, then the answer is yes.

Indeed, if $n+1=p+q$, then $pq-\varphi(pq)=pq-(p-1)(q-1)=pq-(pq-p-q+1)=pq-pq+p+q-1=p+q-1=n+1-1=n$.
If the conjecture holds, then this would cover all the odd numbers greater than $5$.

For any odd prime $p$, one has $p-\varphi(p)=1$. Also, $9-\varphi(9)=9-6=3$ and $25-\varphi(25)=25-20=5$.

So, the function would then be surjective.